# jQuery - catch <input type="button" onclick location based on class

Tags: jquery, button, onclick

I have a button using the onclick fct :

```
<input type="button" onclick="document.location = 'mylocation.html';"  class="button urlToMainDiv" value="Back">
```

I would like to catch the called url using jQuery (based on the used class) to be able to use jQuery.load instead.

I have tried many selectors but I'm not able to catch the called url.

Like this one :

```
jQuery(".urlToMainDiv input").click(function(e){     
     e.preventDefault(); 
    load_ajax_content(this.href,divId,1);       
});
```

Any id or solutions ?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Where is the jQuery??

Comment: I have tried with this (it's working on a)         jQuery(".urlToMainDiv :button").click(function(e){     
       e.preventDefault(); 
  load_ajax_content(this.href,divId,1);
  //}); 
 });

Comment: @Boody Update your question, don't add code in comments, please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('input.button').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this),
        url = $this.attr('onclick').split('=')[1];
    $this.removeAttr('onclick').data('url', url);
}).on('click', function(e) {
    $('#div').load( $(this).data('url') );
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Rttjs/

Comment: Nice, big thanks it's just what I was looking for ! I just add the class into the selector ('input.button.urlToMainDiv').each(function() to stay compatible with the other button.

Answer (score 1):

You can't prevent the native onclick handler in jQuery, you'll have to remove it to moke sure the button does'nt redirect, and before you remove it you'll have to get the URL, and then use the URL in a `load()` function, like so :

```
var url = $('.urlToMainDiv').attr('onclick');
$('.urlToMainDiv').attr('onclick', '');  // removes the onclick function

$('.button').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    url = url.split("'")[1];
    $('#elementId').load(url);
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/2WwAa/)

Comment: Your `var url ...` assignment doesn't quite make sense

Comment: @Madbreaks - does it make more sense now ?

Comment: Yep!  Although I'd probably do the whole assignment on one line, but hey.

Comment: @Madbreaks - how do you suggest to do that ?

Comment: `var url = $('.urlToMainDiv').attr('onclick').split("'")[1]`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm missing something, but just call a custom function in `onclick`:

```
<input type="button" onclick="doLoad('mylocation.html'); return false;"  class="button urlToMainDiv" value="Back">

function doLoad(url){
    // now use jQuery load
}
```

If you are unable to modify the HTML, just overwrite the `onclick`:

```
$('input.urlToMainDiv').attr('onclick', "doLoad('mylocation.html')");
```